# Perl regex strange behaviour

Tags: regex, perl

Method 1:

```
$C_HOME = "$ENV{EO_HOME}\\common\\";
print $C_HOME;
```

gives C:\work\System11R1\common\

ie The environment variable is getting expanded.

Method 2:

Parse properties file having
C_HOME = $ENV{EO_HOME}\common\

```
while(<IN>) {
    if(m/(.*)\s+=\s+(.*)/)
    {
        $o{$1}=$2;
    }
}

$C_HOME = $o{"C_HOME"};
print $C_HOME;
```

This gives a output of $ENV{EO_HOME}\common\

ie The environment variable is not getting expanded.

How do I make sure that the environment variable gets expanded in the second case also.

Comment: What is `$o`, exactly? Where did you initialize it (via `my`--of course, you did this because you **are** using the `strict` and `warnings` pragmas, right)? Try using `Data::Dumper` to see what `$o` contains.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in the line:

```
    $o{$1}=$2;
```

Of course perl will not evaluate `$2` automatically as it read it.

If you want, you can evaluate it manually:

```
    $o{$1}=eval($2);
```

But you must be sure that it is ok from security point of view.

Answer (score 3):

the value of `$o{C_HOME}` contains the literal string `$ENV{C_HOME}\common\`. To get the $ENV-value eval-ed, use `eval`...

```
$C_HOME = eval $o{"C_HOME"};
```

I leave it to you to find out why that will fail, however...

Answer (score 1):

Expression must be evaluated:

```
$C_HOME = eval($o{"C_HOME"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl expands variables in double-quote-like *code* strings, not in *data*.

You have to `eval` a string to explicity interpolate variables inside it, but doing so without checking what you are passing to `eval` is dangerous.

Instead, look for everything you may want to interpolate inside the string and eval those using a regex substitution with the `/ee` modifier.

This program looks for all references to elements of the `%ENV` hash in the config value and replaces them. You may want to add support for whitespace wherever Perl allows it (`$  ENV  {  EO_HOME  }` compiles just fine). It also assigns test values for `%ENV` which you will need to remove.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;

%ENV = ( EO_HOME => 'C:\work\System11R1' );

while (<DATA>) {
    if ( my ($key, $val) = m/ (.*) \s+ = \s* (.*) /x ) {
        $val =~ s/ ( \$ENV \{ \w+ \} ) / $1 /gxee;
        $data{$key} = $val;
    }
}

print $data{C_HOME};


__DATA__
C_HOME = $ENV{EO_HOME}\common\
```

**output**

```
C:\work\System11R1\common\
```